# Value update on the same tick Vue.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a password field on my Vue.JS form that should update a progress bar, the policy is quite simple, I have 5 conditions, each should add 20% to the progress bar. what I have done is 5 `computed` checks for each condition which looks something like this:

```
hasLower() {
  return this.password == null
    ? null
    : /[a-z]/.test(this.password);
}
```

thenI trigger a function at `keyPress` to count how many trues am I getting from the 5 checks and update the value of a counter that is later mapped to the progress bar, like this:

```
    checkPassword() {
  this.trueCounter = 0;
  this.progressBar.value = 0;
  if (this.hasLower) this.trueCounter++;
  if (this.hasUpper) this.trueCounter++;
  if (this.hasDigit) this.trueCounter++;
  if (this.hasSChar) this.trueCounter++;
  if (this.has8) this.trueCounter++;
  console.log("Probe: " + this.trueCounter)
}
```

My problem is that values are updated by the following key press! For example, if I type "a" in the password field, I get 0, if I type it again I get a 1 and it stays like this. then if I type in a character that triggers a different condition "A" for example, I get the last value again and it's changed only by the following Key press.

Is there a way to overcome this one keypress delay so I can always get the updated value immedietly?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set that as a computed value so that it is updated every time the password is updated. Maybe something like below would work better for you?

```
new Vue({
  data: {
        password: ""
  },
  computed: {
        hasLower: function() {
            return this.password && /[a-z]/.test(this.password);
        },
        hasUpper: function() {
          return this.password && /[A-Z]/.test(this.password);
        },
        hasDigit: function() {
          return this.password && /[0-9]/.test(this.password);
        },
        hasSChar: function() {
          return false; // User yours here. I don't know the regex off the tope of my head.
        },
        has8: function() {
          return this.password && this.password.length >= 8;
        },
        password_strength: function() {
            var points = 0;
            if (this.hasLower) points++;
            if (this.hasUpper) points++;
            if (this.hasDigit) points++;
            if (this.hasSChar) points++;
            if (this.has8) points++;
            return points;
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Just realized the original post does not have `()` at the end of those, so I added them. They may well be properties in your code, so no parentheses makes sense that way. I just made them methods.

EDIT2: I take that back, they'll probably be better off as computed properties. Taking a second look, it looks like I've got something very similar to what you have, but as far as I can tell, the password strength is calculated correctly on my end. When the password hits the appropriate checks, the password strength variable is updated appropriately.

Comment: I tried this, it works as well, but it did not solve my problem... I still get the updated value one keystroke later :/

Comment: How do you mean one keystroke later? Mine is instantaneous. Pretty much what's in the password field is reflected exactly by the computed properties. Also, what browser are you using? And what does `progressBar.value` do? In the original code you just set it to 0 and leave it like that.

Comment: I was trying something with that value.. I forgot to remove it, I will redo the whole page with this snippet and see what happens